# jQuery mousemove() In Iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mousemove

i have a question regarding jQuery mousemove() on iPhone. The problem is that it doesn't show the movement on iPhone when touches occur; the events are not working properly in Safari on iPhone.

Can I get any tips of any Javascript plugins to fix this or detect movement on iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and use the virtual events created by that plugin (`vmousemove` for example). More info on the events [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html).

However this framework is NOT compatible with every jQuery plug-in (for example some of jQuery-UI widgets are integrated in it, but in a different way). It probably works for plugin that are not event driven (i.e. that don't change the way the user interract).

An other choice is [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) but I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `touchmove` event. Example of usage:

```
$('#selector').bind('touchmove', function(event)
{
    // your code...
});
```